# Ruby split integer into array of integers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say I have big integer `293649214912`
I want to get the next result:

```rb
[2936, 9364, 3649, 6492, 4921, 9214, 2149, 1491, 4912]
```

Comment: Consider the results of `293649214912 % 10000` and `293649214912 / 10`.

Comment: @Chris : How about converting the number to a string, split the string into an array 4-digit-pieces, and then convert this back to an array of integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One could convert the integer to a string and use a regular expression with [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) or [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-scan).

```
str = 293649214912.to_s
  #=> "293649214912"
```

```
r = /(?=(\d{4}))/
```

```
str.gsub(r).map { $1.to_i }
  #=> [2936, 9364, 3649, 6492, 4921, 9214, 2149, 1491, 4912]
```

This uses the form of `String#gsub` that takes one argument (the *pattern*) and no block, returning an enumerator<sup>1</sup> that I've chained to [Enumerable#map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map).

The regular expression matches a zero-length string (think of the location between successive digits) provided that location is followed by four digits. `(?=(\d{4}))` is a *positive lookahead* that asserts that the match is followed immediately by four digits. Those four digits are not  part of the match that is returned. The four digits are saved in capture group 1, so they may be retrieved within the block. The block variable `_` holds an empty string (the match). I've used an underscore to signal that it is not used in the block calculation (a common convention).

---

Alternatively, `scan` could be used with the same regular expression.<sup>2</sup>

```
str.scan(r).map { |(s)| s.to_i }
  #=> [2936, 9364, 3649, 6492, 4921, 9214, 2149, 1491, 4912]
```

Recall how `scan` treats capture groups: "If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group."

Note that:

```
str.scan(r)
  #=> [["2936"], ["9364"], ["3649"], ["6492"], ["4921"],
  #    ["9214"], ["2149"], ["1491"], ["4912"]]
```

---

If one chooses to stick with integers, here is a variant of @Allan's answer when his argument `n` equals `4`:

```
def construct(n)
  loop.with_object([]) do |_,arr|
    arr.unshift(n % 10_000)
    n /= 10
    break arr if n < 1_000
  end
end
```

```
construct(293649214912)
  #=> [2936, 9364, 3649, 6492, 4921, 9214, 2149, 1491, 4912]
```

This uses the form of [Kernel#loop](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) that does not take a block and returns an enumerator. I've chained that enumerator to [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object).

<sup>1 This form of `gsub` has nothing to do with string replacement: the enumerator `str.gsub(r)` merely generates matches.</sup>

<sup>2. This could instead be written `str.scan(r).map { |a| a.first.to_i }`.</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 5):

This can be done pretty easily using [`Integer#digits`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Integer.html#method-i-digits) and some basic iteration methods from [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html):

```ruby
def split_integer_into_sliding_groups_of_4_digits(n)
  n.
    digits.
    each_cons(4).
    map do |arr|
      arr.each_with_index.reduce(0) {|acc, (d, i)| acc + d * 10 ** i }
    end
end
```

As an alternative, it can also be done via string manipulation:

```ruby
def split_integer_into_sliding_groups_of_4_digits(n)
  n.to_s.each_char.each_cons(4).map(&:join).map(&:to_i)
end
```

Or a mix of the two:

```ruby
def split_integer_into_sliding_groups_of_4_digits(n)
  n.digits.reverse.each_cons(4).map(&:join).map(&:to_i)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is that does it via string manipulations:

```
def split_n(i, n)
  s = i.to_s
  return s.length < n ? 
    [] :
    (0..s.length-n).map { |i| s.slice(i, n).to_i }
  end
end
```

and a integer version:

```
def split_n(i, n)          
    mask = 10**n
    limit = 10**(n-1)
    r = []
    while i > limit do     
      r.unshift(i % mask)   
      i /= 10  
    end
    return r
  end
```